# Laravel update function data not passing to DB but no error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys we are new to Laravel and Stack(hope this is a clear question) and recently made a post trying an update method with ajax and js but returned many problems, and since returned to a basic Laravel function. For some reason we can't quite understand why this function is not returning any data, there aren't any errors since we had parsed through them all.. sql constraints, null data, Symfony handler etc etc.. as well as obviously reading other similar stack questions but with no resolution. We have tried to change the controller function, the method calls (PUT PATCH POST) Does anybody have any suggestions what is going wrong here? I'm sure its really obvious.. thank you!

Quindi.. User clicks edit post, makes edit, confirm.. page refreshes with no changes, no error and no data in database.

```js
 <form id="form-edit-post" action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/update" method="POST" data-parsley-validate>
                        {{  csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

```css
 Route::patch('/posts/{id}/update', [PostsController::class, 'update'])->name('post.update');
```

```php
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {       

        $this->validate($request, array(
            'content' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
        ));

        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->content = $request['content'];
        $post->location = $request['location'];
        $post->update();

        return back()->with('success','Post Updated Successfully');
        
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$post->update()` be `$post->save()`? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates

Comment: @BrianThompson tried now but it creates a new entry in the db and doesn't update the current post? thank you anyway. open to anything

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means `$post` is not being hydrated from the DB, but instead its injecting an empty model. Can you verify that `$post->id` is actually correct in the controller?

Comment: Where is try catch? Use try catch and post error you get from exception. Also this might help  
```$post->update(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id,'content' => $request['content'],'location' => $request['location']])```

Comment: @RajeshPaudel Why add a try/catch? They said there is no error.

Comment: @BrianThompson just making sure if there is error or not. If the post is really not updating then he might be using guarded or fillable incorrectly

Comment: There's no mass-update, so guarded/fillable isn't in play here.

Comment: There's no reason to use [`update`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_update) since its meant to be passed an array of attributes to update and you're manually setting the attributes. So `save` is the correct option. `update` returns false if the model does not exist in the DB. `save()` will create a new entry if it does not exist. This is what is leading me to think that its not actually finding your post by the ID in the route type-hint.

Comment: @BrianThompson you have saved the day! Thank you! I will update the post to show what worked! How do we buy you a beer Thank you so much!

Comment: @BrianThompson yea they have dependency injection happening instead of route model binding since the route parameter is named `id` not `post`

Comment: @lagbox You are correct, here are the relevant [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) on the subject for reference to the OP and others. I missed that detail since I don't use route-model binding often..

Answer (score 0):

credit to @Brian Thompson!
Such a simple fix. use find method to find the id in controller (obviously), use save() not update().

```html
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {       

        $post = Post::find($request->input('postid'));
        
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'content' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
        ));

        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->content = $request['content'];
        $post->location = $request['location'];
        $post->save();

        return back()->with('success','Post Updated Successfully');
        
    }
```